# filter arrays from multidimensional array which value is gather than or equal to x in php

Tags: php, arrays

here is my array

```
array (
    3 => array (
            0 => 5,
            1 => 3,
            2 => 1
        ),

    4 => array (
            0 => 4
        ),

    2 => array (
            0 => 2
       )
);
```

I want to get items from this array which value is gather than or equal to 4.

Something like to:

```
array (
    3 => array (
            0 => 5,
            1 => 3,
            2 => 1
        ),

    4 => array (
            0 => 4
        )
);
```

how can I do it in fast method? sorry for my english.

Comment: *greater than or equal to 4*? But your expected output has 1 and 3.

Comment: With `array_filter` and custom callback.

Comment: explain the result you want in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print_r(array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($v) { return max($v) >= 4; }
));
```